# Puppeteer - Cannot read property 'executablePath' of undefined

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Regardless what i tried , i'm always getting executablePath is undefined. Unfortunately there's not much info on this on google. It would be great anyone could let me know where to dig into deeper to solve this error. revisionInfo is returning undefined.

Error

```
BrowserFetcher {
  _product: 'chrome',
  _downloadsFolder: '/var/www/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium',
  _downloadHost: 'https://storage.googleapis.com',
  _platform: 'linux' }
TypeError: Cannot read property 'executablePath' of undefined
    at demo1 (/var/www/filename.js:10:36)
```

Source Code

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

const demo1 = async () => {
  try {
    const browserFetcher = puppeteer.createBrowserFetcher();
    console.log(browserFetcher);
    const revisionInfo = await browserFetcher.download('970485');
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      executablePath: revisionInfo.executablePath,
      args: ['--window-size=1920,1080', '--disable-notifications'],
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({
      width: 1080,
      height: 1080,
    });
    await page.goto('https://example.com', {
      waitUntil: 'networkidle0',
    });

    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};

demo1();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into two things

1. If you did a apt install chromium-browser , remove that
2. Try run and install using a x86 server instead of ARM based Server (t4g instance by aws)

Either one of those solved my issue. The code was still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error message, the problem is with this line

```js
      executablePath: revisionInfo.executablePath,
```

where `revisionInfo` is undefined, meaning this does not give you the data you want:

```js
    const revisionInfo = await browserFetcher.download('970485');
```

If you really need a specific `executablePath`, you need to make sure that `revisionInfo` gets the value you want.

Otherwise, you can just remove the line       `executablePath: revisionInfo.executablePath,` and let puppeteer use its default chromium browser.